# How to sum the count of sales in a panda dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, plotly-dash

I have a database of sales of real estate agents. Sales are credited to their salesman ID (NRDS#). Some sales will be the same NRDS number as agents may have both sides of a transaction.

I am able to count the sales for each category (listagent / buyersagent) using these lines of code:

`dataListYTDBuyer = dataYTD.groupby('buyersagent')['buyersagent'].count().reset_index(name="count") dataListYTDBuyer = dataListYTDBuyer.sort_values('count', ascending=False)`

`dataListYTDList = dataYTD.groupby('listagent')['listagent'].count().reset_index(name="count") dataListYTDList = dataListYTDList.sort_values('count', ascending=False)`

This produces:

```
buyersagent  count_x    listagent  count_y

0     635504004     1530  635504004.0    105.0

1     230010894      166  230010894.0     94.0
2     230018849      148  230018849.0     21.0
3     230015231      144  230015231.0    141.0
4     230014480      140  230014480.0    101.0
..          ...      ...          ...      ...
94    230003099       16  230003099.0     61.0
95    230010244       16  230010244.0     21.0
96    230018166       16          NaN      NaN
97    230016463       16  230016463.0      2.0
98    230016335       16  230016335.0     42.0
```

I am stuck on how to add and rank order the combined number of sales, though (the NaN is that salesperson did not list any homes). I tried:

```
sum_sales = dataListYTDList['count'] + dataListYTDBuyer['count']
```

But that is of course not (I don't think) adding the appropriate set of numbers together (that is, summing the sales of each salesperson). Any advice appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the data frame you show is not one, but two frames? And what you want to do is sum up the count of sales by agent ID, regardless of whether they're the buying or selling agent?

If I've understood correctly, then you can merge the two data frames on the IDs, and then you can sum up the sales counts.

```py
df_merged = pandas.merge(
    dataListYTDList, 
    dataListYTDBuyer, 
    left_on='buyersagent', 
    right_on='listagent')

df_merged['total_sales'] = df_merged['count_x'].add(df_merged['count_y'])
```

I think that should do it.